# UIImageView+AFNetworking maxConcurrentOperationCount

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

This awesome `UIImageView` extension has the `af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue`, where max concurrent number set as

`_af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount;`

How to access this private field and set custom value for `maxConcurrentOperationCount`? (I don't want to edit files under CocoaPods directly)

UPD: Thanks GeneratorOfOne, looks like the best solution for me. However, I decided to use SDWebImage, because it provides cache out of the box and allows to set `maxConcurrentOperationCount` in a line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a private method which has a static NSOperationQueue. You could either go and poke the code directly which is not good to change the existing code for some librarues. I would suggest you to create a new UIImageView category, where you would expose this method and then you could set the maxConcurrentOperationCount on it.

Like,

```
@interface UIImageView(MyExtension)
  + (NSOperationQueue *)af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue;
@end

@implementation UIImageView(MyExtension)
  + (void)load {
     NSOperationQueue *queue = [self af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue];
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;
  }
@end
```

Then, you could now include the extension in your class and set its maxConcurrentOperationCount.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the definition NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount is meant to return the correct amount of concurrent queues allowed based on system conditions.

Why would you want to limit it?